# Enabling local gpu for jupyter notebook. Unable to install tensorflow 2.3.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, anaconda, gpu

I have geforce gtx 1650 gpu in my windows 10 pro laptop. I want to enable gpu while I work in jupyter notebook. According to a resource it said
-- the GeForce GTX 1650 is supported by cuDNN 7.6, Cuda 10.1 and Tensorflow 2.3.0; --

For these versions python must be [3.6 to 3.8](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).
I have installed python 3.8.7.

How do I open jupyter lab/notebook here? Then how to install tensorflow 2.3.0?

Before I did all this the jupyter notebook command worked fine.

To reduce python version in jupyter lab, I tried deactivating conda version and I got this.
[image]

[image]

Now I cant open notebook from anaconda prompt. I want to open it and **install tensorflow 2.3.0** and most importantly **enable my laptop gpu to use in it.**

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)